# Add LocalDb support. Drop SQL Compact?

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-2012

I have built a web application on asp.net mvc 4 using a SQL Server Compact database, need to use ms sql server express, is there any way i can get entire schema of compact database copied to new sql server express, there are around 35 tables?

Thanks
Varun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Compct Toolbox (standalone and VS add-in) to script the SQL Compact file and it can also migrate directly

Comment: I tried working http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/ with codefirst. it worked. thanks